# Cannot port forward for app

Tags: openshift

I am trying to use:

```
rhc port-forward -a <appname>
```

But keep getting the error:

**checking available ports...none 
There are no available ports to forward for this application. Your application may be stopped or idled**

I can browse to my app, and I've restarted it several times from the web frontend.

Can anyone tell me how I can get port forward to work?

EDIT: When I use debug:

```
DEBUG: Using config file C:/Users/matthew.harris/.openshift/express.conf
DEBUG: Git config '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" config --get rhc.app
-id' returned ''
DEBUG: Git config '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" config --get rhc.app
 -name' returned ''
DEBUG: Git config '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" config --get rhc.dom
ain-name' returned ''
DEBUG: Authenticating with RHC::Auth::Token
DEBUG: Connecting to https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Getting all domains
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 200 2441 ms
DEBUG: Server supports API versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG:    Using API version 1.7
DEBUG: Client API version 1.7 is not current. Refetching API
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 200  154 ms
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains
DEBUG:    code 200  109 ms
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Request GET     https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/mharrisweb/ap
plication/node
DEBUG:    code 200  210 ms
Checking available ports ... DEBUG: /usr/bin/rhc-list-ports: line 32:     127.5.42.1
30:27017: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is     ".5.42.130:2
7017")
DEBUG: Getting all gear groups for application node
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Request GET         https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/application/5501b0c0
4382ecfefe0000a2/gear_groups
DEBUG:    code 200  384 ms`
```

Comment: What cartridges are you using for your application? You can view them with the "rhc app show" command.

Comment: MongoDB 2.4 and RockMongo 1.1